# WDS Unattended Answer File - Not Auto Logging-In to Domain

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10, wds, unattended

I am trying to create an Answer file to pass domain login credentials (not to join the domain) when the WDS server is booted via PXE to install Windows 10 on a laptop.  The server is on the domain and is running Window Server 2016 Standard version 1607 OS build 14393.5786.

I have followed several examples on this website as well as other walkthroughs, but not having any luck getting this to recognize.

I am generating the file through WSIM with the only component being the WDS Login Credentials and the language settings.  Credentials are added as the format below.  I setup the UI language so it bypasses the "Next" button when it first boots.

- Domain: Domainname.com (which is the FQDN)
- Password: mypassword
- Username: domainname/username (the domain name minus the ".com")

[WSIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRnhj.png)

I have tried different combinations in the answer file, however I am able to manually type my credentials in that format when the login window pops up.  The system will also accept username@domainname.com when typed in manually
[WDS Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdb1t.jpg)

I have my answer file attached to the Install Image Properties as well as the Server Properties in the Client tab
[Install Image Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru7Cv.png)
[Server Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h97Ei.png)

Here is the message I am getting.  Which cannot be true because if I take away the unattend file, and type in credentials manually (as stated above), it will let me continue.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56WKO.png)

Am I missing a piece to the Answer file creation?  Why won't it accept the same credentials in the answer file.  Here is the copy+paste from the file which was generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>us-US</UILanguage>
                <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>us-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>us-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>us-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>us-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <WindowsDeploymentServices>
                <Login>
                    <Credentials>
                        <Domain>domain.com</Domain>
                        <Password>mypassword</Password>
                        <Username>domain\username</Username>
                    </Credentials>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </Login>
            </WindowsDeploymentServices>
            <EnableNetwork>true</EnableNetwork>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/win10/install.wim#Windows 10 Pro" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
<Domain>domain</Domain>
<Password>mypassword</Password>
<Username>domain\username</Username>
```

or

```
<Domain>domain</Domain>
<Password>mypassword</Password>
<Username>username</Username>
```

domain = whatever the domain is called